# Sql Express 2012 Upgrade to SP1

Tags: team-foundation-server, sql-server-2012, service-pack

I have Sql Server Express 2012 installed on one server. As I'm trying to install TFS 2015 and it require Sql Express 2012 with SP1 I would like just to update my instance to SP1, but I can't find a way.

From MS website I see this ([at this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579)):

> **Installation for the Existing Users**
>
> If you have an existing installation of Express with Tools, SQL
>   Server Management Studio Express, or Express with Advanced Services,
>   and want to add the complete SQL Server Management Studio feature to
>   your Express instance, do the following:
>
> Step 1: ...

It seems that there is not a way to just update my existing instance with the service pack, but I need to uninstall everything and re install.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service pack should be delivered through windows update. Make sure you select in the settings section to also include updates of other Microsoft products.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to check now

Comment: I see "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 3" from the optiona updates, will this install also SP1 and SP2? (Sorry for the question that can look stupid, but I'm not a system admin :) )

Comment: Yes, the latest SP will always include all other fixes

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot, I have done it and now I have been able to install properly TFS

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I wanted to setup SQL Server 2012 to fix an old application in new Windows 10. We have the original installation .iso with sp1. After few weeks of installing, it didn't update to latest SP or gives an option to update through Windows updates. It look like in new Windows 10 installations it does not pick up old SQL Server editions or may be unsupported editions.

Then after searching the internet I found this link "[KB2755533 - How to obtain the latest service pack for SQL Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb2755533-how-to-obtain-the-latest-service-pack-for-sql-server-2012-aea27612-81a4-357d-b6f6-c1eeb5966768)"

Basically just download the latest Service Pack (SP4) for the your machine architecture (x64 or x86) and run it to complete the update.